# Nvidia GTX 1050 and Intel HD on Ubuntu 16.04 (Dell 9560) - super bad Nvidia performance

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I have read loads about Linux, kernels and Nvidia over the past few days but I can't solve the issue described here below.

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my Dell 9560 after completely wiping the HD. 
the kernel is `4.8.0-51-generic` from the standard Ubuntu PPA.

The computer has two graphics cards: an Intel HD and a Nvidia GTX 1050.

I have installed the Nvidia driver `sudo aptitude install nvidia-375` from the PPA `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa` and in the `nvidia-settings` - which I use with the accompanying GUI - the section "Nvidia Prime" allows me to choose between the Intel HD and the Nvidia card.

However, when I select my Nvidia card, software like Lightworks performs much worse than when I have selected my Intel HD card whose hardware is nowhere near that of the Nvidia's. Even when I scroll in Firefox the Intel HD seems to do a much better job.

I have tried `nvidia-381` but the issue persists. Any ideas if there is a workaround?

Any pros here who would recommend to use some 'grub & modprobe' trick?

Comment: What performance is the problem?  There is a known tearing problem with the laptop Nvidia/Intel combination.

Comment: GPU performance is the problem. It's for video editing, not gaming.

Comment: Did you look at the Nvidia-settings, GPU section, and performance level?  Do you have any UEFI settings/BIOS items to select the amount of memory dedicated to the GPU?  How much memory do you have (syste./GPU)?

Comment: I suggest you disable the Intel card in the BIOS.

Comment: The Nvidia-settings show the expected parameters. The BIOS doesn't offer any memory allocation for the GPU. Also, in the BIOS it is not possible to disable the Intel card. 
My system has 32GB RAM (2400 Mhz) and the Nvidia card has 4 GB RAM.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "worse performance"? Are you talking about frames-per-second? Or is there lots of tearing and jank/stutter?

Comment: Hi Andy, I was talking in comparison to the Intel HD 630 performances. Frames per second of 1080p video playback with some simple colour correction in Lightworks.

Comment: Perhaps update your question so it includes the output of `lshw -C video` and `nvidia-smi`. I've been using Nvidia drivers with Ubuntu/Kubuntu for years, and the only issue I've had with it is tearing, but this was easily solved by opening the Nvidia settings, clicking on `X Server Display Configuration`, then clicking the `Advanced` button, then making sure `Force Composition Pipeline` is checked. I currently have a 1070 in my desktop, and a 980m in my laptop, and both work awesomely with the `nvidia-384` driver. It can be very tricky getting Nvidia to work perfectly on PRIME laptops.